# Update a Hash Where the Values are Hashes

Tags: ruby

I have this hash where the keys are 0, 3, and 5 and the values are hashes.

```
{0=>{:occurrences=>1, :className=>"class"},
 3=>{:occurrences=>3, :className=>"hello"},
 5=>{:occurrences=>3, :className=>"nah"}}
```

How can I implement something like this:

```
h.map { |key| 
  if key[:occurrences] > 2
    key[:occurrences] += 1 
  end
}
```

I know this syntax doesn't work. I want to increment the occurrence value when a condition is met and I am not sure how to access the key of a key but I would like the result to be:

```
{0=>{:occurrences=>1, :className=>"class"}, 
 3=>{:occurrences=>4, :className=>"hello"}, 
 5=>{:occurrences=>4, :className=>"nah"}}
```

Comment: Please post the desired output as right now I am a bit confused

Comment: For example I would want the entire hash returned but with updated values: {0=>{:occurrence=>1, :className=>"class"}, 3=>{:occurrences=>4, :className=>"hello"}, 5=>{:occurrences=>4, :className=>"nah"}}. If the value of the occurrences key is greater than two than I want to increment that value and still have the entire hash.

Comment: that output is the same as the input. I have added it to your question please update as needed

Comment: your input and output are identical

Comment: No the occurrences for the keys 3 and 5 have been incremented in the output. I apologize for the confusion. I want the entire hash still in tact but with slight modifications.

Comment: That's not how it appears on my screen. Perhaps if I post it again: {0=>{:occurrence=>1, :className=>"class"}, 3=>{:occurrences=>4, :className=>"hello"}, 5=>{:occurrences=>4, :className=>"nah"}}

Comment: @ChickEvans do your hashes really have keys `:occurrence` (singular) and `:occurrences` (plural) based on its value?

Comment: @Stefan No there should not be a difference. I'll correct that typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the existing hash you can simply call [`each_value`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-each_value). It passes each value in your hash to the block and within the block you can update the value (based on a condition):

```
h = {
  0=>{:occurrences=>1, :className=>"class"},
  3=>{:occurrences=>3, :className=>"hello"},
  5=>{:occurrences=>3, :className=>"nah"}
}

h.each_value { |v| v[:occurrences] += 1 if v[:occurrences] > 2 }
#=> {
#     0=>{:occurrences=>1, :className=>"class"},
#     3=>{:occurrences=>4, :className=>"hello"},
#     5=>{:occurrences=>4, :className=>"nah"}
#   }
```

Comment: `to_i` in my answer is not that blind. The original input has both plural and singular names for that attribute (depending on whether it’s greater than one or not.)

Comment: @mudasobwa I assumed that was a typo. Otherwise we'd have to transition from `occurrences: 0` to `occurrence: 1` to `occurrences: 2` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Just out of curiosity:

```
input.map do |k, v|
  [k, v[:occurrences].to_i > 2 ? v.merge(occurrences: v[:occurrences] + 1) : v]
end.to_h
#⇒ {0=>{:occurrence=>1, :className=>"class"},
#   3=>{:occurrences=>4, :className=>"hello"},
#   5=>{:occurrences=>4, :className=>"nah"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
h = { 0=>{ :occurrences=>1, :className=>"class" },
      3=>{ :occurrences=>3, :className=>"hello" },
      5=>{ :occurrences=>3, :className=>"nah"   } }

f = h.dup
```

**Non-destructive case**

```
h.transform_values do |g|
  g[:occurrences] > 2 ? g.merge(occurrences: g[:occurrences] + 1) : g
end
  #=> { 0=>{ :occurrences=>1, :className=>"class" }, 
  #     3=>{ :occurrences=>4, :className=>"hello" },
  #     5=>{ :occurrences=>4, :className=>"nah"   } }

h == f
  #=> true
```

**Destructive case**

```
g = h.transform_values! do |g|
  g[:occurrences] > 2 ? g.merge(occurrences: g[:occurrences] + 1) : g
end
  #=> { 0=>{ :occurrences=>1, :className=>"class" },
  #     3=>{ :occurrences=>4, :className=>"hello" },
  #     5=>{ :occurrences=>4, :className=>"nah"   } }
h == g
```

See [Hash#transform_values](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html) and [Hash#transform_values!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values-21), which made their debut in MRI v.2.4. Note that, in the destructive case, `merge!` is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

> For example I would want the entire hash returned but with updated
>   values: {0=>{:occurrence=>1, :className=>"class"},
>   3=>{:occurrences=>4, :className=>"hello"}, 5=>{:occurrences=>4,
>   :className=>"nah"}}. If the value of the occurrences key is greater
>   than two than I want to increment that value and still have the entire
>   hash.

Here you go:

```
h = {0=>{:occurrences=>1, :className=>"class"}, 3=>{:occurrences=>3, :className=>"hello"}, 5=>{:occurrences=>3, :className=>"nah"}}

new_h = h.map do |k, v| 
  if v[:occurrences] > 2
    v[:occurrences] += 1 
  end

  [k, v]
end.to_h
```

Comment: What is happening at the end with the [k, v]?

Comment: @ChickEvans that's the block's return value, i.e. the new key-value pair.

Comment: Either return a new hash or modify the existing one, but don't do both things.

Comment: I intended to modify the existing one. Is there a benefit to returning a new one?

Comment: @ChickEvans not necessarily, either one is fine, but returning a new hash **and** modifying the existing one can be a source of confusion and may result in hard to find bugs.

Comment: Can I do this to update the v[:occurrences] of a specific key? Like this: new_h = h.map do |k, v| if k == 3 v[:occurrences] += 1 end [k, v] end.to_h.